# how to navigate to a named router-outlet by running a function on click? in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

i used this method to navigate to named router-outlet => ( link -> [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'dashboard': ['userprofile'] } }] & Router-oulet ->  ) , now how can i navigate to this router by a function? or how to use outlet name in "this.router.navigate" ?

route to this ->

```
<router-outlet name="dashboard"></router-outlet>
```

by this link in html template ->

```
[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'dashboard': ['userprofile'] } }]
```

now, how can i navigate to the **dashboard** router-outlet by running a function? using **this.router.navigate?**

Comment: now, i used second router-outlet named "popup" **<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet> ** inside a modal and that shows error -> **cannot find the outlet pop to load ** ...?!

Comment: i solved it by writing the    **<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet> **  under the primary <router-outlet>.. thumbs up!

Answer (score 3):

It should look more or less like:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {'dashboard':'userprofile'}}],{
  relativeTo: this.route
});
```

Comment: shows error -> relative to is not assignable to navigation extras!

Comment: this.router.navigate([{outlets: {'dashboard':'userprofile'}},{relativeTo: this.route}]);  -> this syntax gives no error

Comment: from where should i import **route** ?

Comment: route is an injected instance of ActivatedRoute, import from @angular/router